# Calling External Python script works inside QT Creator but not outside

Tags: python, qt, qprocess

I am trying to  Call a Python Script form inside a QT GUI application. It works inside QT Creator but when I run the program outside the python script does not seem to execute.

I tried this:

```
QProcess::execute("python",QStringList() << "Browse.py" << "Firefox" << "https://www.n11.com/magaza/tozbitti?iw=motor&pg=" << "2" << "4");
```

and this:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
       process->startDetached("python", "QStringList() << "Browse.py" << "Firefox" << "https://www.n11.com/magaza/tozbitti?iw=motor&pg=" << "2" << "4");
       process->waitForFinished();
       process->close();
```

Both work when I run the program from inside QT Creator ide but from outside they do not seem to work. Any reason why or how else I can solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: change `Browse.py` with fullpath

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: It seems that the python used inside the QT Creator is different from the python used outside. So, I reinstalled the python module on the other version and now it is working.